# how to reset git credential for specific repository address

Tags: git, git-clone

I can not clone to a specific repository after entering wrong credential at the first time cloning. How can I reset or modify git config to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
git config credential.helper ""
```

This should clear the credentials from your local Git folder. The credentials are not safe because they are not encrypted. A better alternative might be to use SSH keys.

Comment: did not work, It results the same

Comment: Ok, try: git credential-manager clear

Comment: error: remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied and fatal: Authentication failed for 'https...'

Comment: Ok, try this: git remote show origin

Answer (score 0):

The following steps work for me:

Display the system config file: `git config --system -l`

There you see one line (at the end) like this:

`credential.helper=osxkeychain` (I'm a MacOS user)

To remove this entry write:

`git config --system --unset credential.helper`

And now, the credentials are forgotten and if you make a new push, you must add your username and password.